# How to cast JSON response (PersistanceVector) to Map?

Tags: json, clojure

Is there a simple and quick way to convert `PersistentVector` to `Map`?

I have a `clojure.data.json/read-str` whitch returns me data in format like this:

```
[{:AMD "406.51\r", :LSL "9.782\r", :DOP "42.55\r", ...}]
```

but i would like to have a map like this: `{:AMD "406.51", :LSL "9.782"}`.

I would use this data later to show it on U/I using hiccup.
Is there any better solutions than this ,,conversion'' of data?

Help, please. I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vector has only one map, you can use `first` to get only that map, outside the vector. If there are multiple maps, you need to decide how you will organize each of them into a larger map, `merge`, `merge-with`, and `group-by` are all likely candidates.

Also, to literally get the output you show from the input you show, you can do the following:

```
(-> json-input
    clojure.data.json/read-str
    first
    (select-keys [:AMD :LSL]))
```